# Adding an item to listpreference

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I have a preference screen containing a preferenceList. i want the user to be able to add new friends to that list.

I have been unable to find any examples of how i can achieve such a thing doing run time.

Does anyone have an example or able to give me an example of how i would achieve this?

Here is my preference:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Your competetion">
            <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="secondPrefScreen"
        android:summary="click here to see your friends"
        android:title="Friends" >
        <ListPreference
            android:key="friendList"
                />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ListPreference` object at runtime and use the setter and getter methods to update the entries. [ListPreference Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html)

Assuming you are inside a PreferenceActivity:

```
   PreferenceScreen root = this.getPreferenceScreen();
   ListPreference list = (ListPreference) root.findPreference("secondPrefScreen");
   // do stuff with list
```

Comment: and if im not in my preferenceActivity?

Comment: If you want to add these friends from another activity, you can always use a SQL database to store those friends and then display them in the preference list by reading from the database.